# What is the most pythonic way to retrieve the indexes of values sorted by the values?

Tags: python, list, sorting

I have a list `a = [1, 5, 2, 8]`

I need a function that will return the indexes of the entries sorted by their values, i.e. 
    `b = [3, 1, 2, 0]`

I came up with a function to do this:

```
def indices_sorted_by_val(a, reverse=True):
    return [ y[0] for y in  sorted( [(i,a[i]) for i in range(len(a))], key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=reverse )]
```

But it's messy and hard to read. Is there a more pythonic way?

Comment: `[i[0] for i in sorted(enumerate(a), key=lambda x:x[1], reverse=reverse)]` or `np.argsort(a)[::-1 if reverse else None]` to use the numpy approach.

Comment: Thanks Martijn! Will try numpy's argsort

Answer (score 0):

First try ...
`enumerate` will help. I vote against a one-liner, because readibility counts

```
a = [1, 5, 2, 8]

sorted_tuples = sorted(enumerate(a), key= lambda x: x[1], reverse=True)
print([index for index, value in sorted_tuples])
```

Comment: There was a reason I closed this as a duplicate *4 whole minutes before you posted this*.

Comment: I did not see it on time, sorry.